# My C++ bootloader is not working as it should

Tags: c++, inline-assembly, bootloader

I decided that I want to write my own boot-loader completely in C++ but some functions using inline assembly seem like they only work once.

```
//boot.cpp
asm(".code16gcc\n");
asm(".text");
asm("jmpl $0x0000, $main\n");

#include "../libs/os.hpp"

void main()
{
    x16::video::setvideomode(0x03);
    x16::video::printchar('H');
    x16::video::printchar('e');
    x16::video::printchar('l');
    x16::video::printchar('l');
    x16::video::printchar('o');
}
```

```
//os.hpp
#ifndef OS_HPP
#define OS_HPP

typedef unsigned char byte;
typedef unsigned short word;
typedef unsigned long dword;

namespace x16
{
    namespace assembly
    {
        namespace regs
        {
            const int ax = 0, ah = 1, al = 2;
            const int bx = 3, bh = 4, bl = 5;
            const int cx = 6, ch = 7, cl = 8;
            const int dx = 9, dh = 10, dl = 11;
        }
        void setreg8(int reg, byte value)
        {
            if (reg == regs::ah) { asm volatile("movb %0, %%ah" : : "r"(value)); }
            if (reg == regs::al) { asm volatile("movb %0, %%al" : : "r"(value)); }
            if (reg == regs::bh) { asm volatile("movb %0, %%bh" : : "r"(value)); }
            if (reg == regs::bl) { asm volatile("movb %0, %%bl" : : "r"(value)); }
            if (reg == regs::ch) { asm volatile("movb %0, %%ch" : : "r"(value)); }
            if (reg == regs::cl) { asm volatile("movb %0, %%cl" : : "r"(value)); }
            if (reg == regs::dh) { asm volatile("movb %0, %%dh" : : "r"(value)); }
            if (reg == regs::dl) { asm volatile("movb %0, %%dl" : : "r"(value)); }
        }
        void interrupt(int interrupt)
        {
            if (interrupt == 0x10) { asm("int $0x10"); }
            if (interrupt == 0x13) { asm("int $0x13"); }
            if (interrupt == 0x16) { asm("int $0x16"); }
        }
    }
    namespace video
    {
        void setvideomode(byte videomode)
        {
            x16::assembly::setreg8(x16::assembly::regs::ah, 0x00);
            x16::assembly::setreg8(x16::assembly::regs::al, videomode);
            x16::assembly::interrupt(0x10);
        }
        void printchar(byte chr)
        {
            x16::assembly::setreg8(x16::assembly::regs::ah, 0x0E);
            x16::assembly::setreg8(x16::assembly::regs::al, chr);
            x16::assembly::interrupt(0x10);
        }
    }
}

#endif
```

```
//boot.ld
ENTRY(main)
OUTPUT_FORMAT(binary)
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x7C00;
    .text : AT(0x7C00) { *(.text) }
    .sig : AT(0x7DFE) { SHORT(0xAA55); }
}
```

The program should change the videomode to 0x03 and print "Hello" but on qemu only one 'H' appears.
I compile it with:

g++ -c -g -Os -ffreestanding -fwhole-program -Wall -Werror src/boot/boot.cpp -o tmp/boot.o
ld -static -T src/boot/boot.ld -nostdlib --nmagic -o tmp/boot.bin tmp/boot.o

Comment: Seems like you've mistake in your bios output function. Check manual https://wiki.osdev.org/Printing_To_Screen

Comment: Can you show us the assembly code that it compiles to? (you might want to delete the `l`, `l` and `o` to make it shorter)

Comment: Note things like `asm volatile("movb %0, %%dl" : : "r"(value));` won't guarantee that DL will remain that value until you intend to use it with something like  `asm("int $0x10");` . Clobbering DL (or any register) without telling the compiler could in fact cause the code to fail if the compiler was using that register to hold other information.

Comment: As well you need to set DS=ES=SS=0 (you also need to setup a proper stack in SS:SP). You only appears to set CS to 0 with the far jmp at the beginning.

Comment: I recommend not writing the bootloader in C++.  Often, the bootloader area is limited in space.  The C++ runtime library takes up space, that could be used for initializing or loading applications.

Comment: Well the C++ runtime won't be usable in this kind of code since they are using `-ffreestanding` . I concur about not using C++ unless it is something that can target 16-bit code. Watcom c/c++ compiler could be used. The other thing with C++ code would be proper execution of the global constructors ahead of time (and I don't see that happening here either). I'd personally stick to assembly for the bootloader.

Comment: `setreg8()` looks like an insane attempt to use an optimizing C++ compiler as an assembler, so you're still having to write multiple lines of C++ every time you want to invoke an `int $0x10` function vs. if you'd written a `putchar()` or a single block that uses an `"i"` constraint for an interrupt number, and with AH and AL input operands.  (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html or an `"a"` constraint for a `uint8_t` to force gcc to pick AL. Or an `"a"` constraint for a `uint16_t` to get AH:AL set together from `(ah<<8) | al`.

Comment: It's super broken because of missing clobbers, and the assumption that registers won't be modified by the compiler-generated code to set up inputs for the next asm statement.  (Or to evaluate the `if` at run-time if you ever compile without full optimization!  Make it a template param to avoid that risk, but really just don't.)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for helping. I searched a bit, got rid of all the assembly functions and this is it.

```
#ifndef OS_HPP
#define OS_HPP

typedef unsigned char byte;
typedef unsigned short word;
typedef unsigned long dword;

namespace x16
{
    namespace memory
    {
        void writememory(dword address, byte value) { byte* mem = (byte*)address; *mem = value; }
        byte readmemory(dword address) { byte* mem = (byte*)address; return *mem; }
    }
    namespace video
    {
        void setvideomode(byte videomode) { asm("int $0x10" : : "a"(0x0000 | videomode)); }
        word getvideomode()
        {
            word videomode;
            asm("movb $0x0F, %%ah\n"
                "int $0x10\n"
                "movb %%al, %0" : "=r"(videomode));
            return videomode;
        }
        void printchar(byte chr) { asm("int $0x10" : : "a"(0x0e00 | chr)); }
    }
}

#endif
```

Everything is working now. To be honest I don't know much of the things you said because I just started but thank you anyways

Comment: And yeah I know that I shouldn't do it in C++ but I'm new and I want to get experience and I won't even try getting it to be good and efficient.

Comment: This is better; `setvideomode` and `printchar` I think look sane, assuming those `int` functions don't have a return value anywhere.  But you forgot to declare a clobber on AX in `getvideomode`, despite your code modifying both AH and (via `int $0x10`) AL.  Use an `"=a"(videomode)` output operand to tell the compiler that to take AX as the value of `videomode`.  (Since it's a `word` variable, an `a` constraint means AX.  If it was a `uint8_t`, it would mean `AL`.)